# mysql query for storing string array in php SQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, escaping

I have a php form , where the formfields are array of strings.Following is the code to extract a string from the array and save it in the databse with other extracted strings.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO student (formid,firstname,lastname,dob,school,year,sex,touch,reason,other,need,improve1) values";  

$valuesArr = array();
$i=0;
for ($i=1; $i <=$childtoen; $i++) //childtoen is a form variable
        { 
            $improve_list="";
        if ($improve[$i][0]!="") // converting this array to a list 
                {

                    $improve_list = implode( ',', $improve[$i]);$improve_list = mysql_real_escape_string( $improve_list ); 
                }

    $improve_list = mysql_real_escape_string($improve_list);
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string( $firstname[$i] );
    $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string( $lastname[$i] );
    $dob = mysql_real_escape_string( $dob[$i] );
    $school = mysql_real_escape_string( $school[$i] );
    $year = mysql_real_escape_string( $year[$i] );
    $sex = mysql_real_escape_string( $sex[$i] );
    $touch1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $touch[$i] );
    $reason = mysql_real_escape_string( $reason[$i] );
    $other = mysql_real_escape_string( $other[$i] );
    $need = mysql_real_escape_string( $need[$i] );


    $valuesArr[] = "('$id', '$firstname' , '$lastname' , '$dob' , '$school' , '$year' , '$sex' , '$touch1' , '$reason' , '$other' , '$need' , '$improve_list')"; // Error at or near reason


$sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);

$query=mysql_query($sql,$connection); if(!$query) exit(mysql_error());
echo $query; 
}
```

Now i am receiving the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server for the right syntax to use near '('23', '12321' , '12321' , '01/22/2015' , '321' , '3' , 'male' , 'yes' , 'Interv' at line 1
>   where `interv` is actually `Intervention` and is the value of `$reason`
>   I tried to change the enclosing quotes of fields from single ' ' to  double " " in the valuesArr but no help. Unable to get the reason of error

Comment: This line: `$valuesArr[] = ...` adds 1 element to the array and doesn't makes any sense! Just change this line: `$valuesArr[] = ...` to: `$valuesArr = ...` and then: `$sql .= $valuesArr;`

Comment: Leave a space after values in the first part of $sql.Also do a basic debugging,echo out your $sql at the end.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).

Comment: @Rizier123 if i change it to $valuesArr it throws this error
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

Comment: After doing what Rizier123 says `echo $sql;` so you can see th query and identify the problem.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I ll keep this in mind

Comment: @JayBlanchard that comment was for using mysqli and PDO 
and echo $sql 
`INSERT INTO student (formid,firstname,lastname,dob,school,year,sex,touch,reason,other,need,improve1) valuesYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

Comment: Where are your values in the query? You need to echo `$sql` after you append the values.

Comment: @JayBlanchard i placed the echo statement right after the 
`$sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);` statment

Comment: Get rid of the `implode`. Just do `$sql .= $valuesArr`. BTW, an array is not needed here.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Oh great thanks i did it and the Query worked but only the first row has the right values the second row is stripping the values 
`INSERT INTO student (formid,firstname,lastname,dob,school,year,sex,touch,reason,other,need,improve1) values('29', '12321' , '12321' , '01/22/2015' , '321' , '3' , 'male' , 'no' , 'Intervention' , '12321' , 'no' , 'ADHDandAUTISMandDYSPRAXIAandOther')1INSERT INTO student (formid,firstname,lastname,dob,school,year,sex,touch,reason,other,need,improve1) values('29', '3' , '3' , '/' , '1' , '' , 'l' , 'no' , 't' , '3' , '' , 'fooandfoo')1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't resetting `$sql`. The second time through the loop, it still has the value it had from the first time through the loop.

So, you're appending a new list of values onto the previous statement. As a short demonstration, the first time through the loop, `$sql` has a value of:

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('fee')
```

Second time through the loop, `$sql` has a value of:

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('fee')('fi')
                                    ^
```

And MySQL is going to throw a syntax error right there: **`('fi'`**

As a quick fix, move the initial assignment,  `$sql = "INSERT INTO ...` inside  the `for` loop, like right before you append the imploded `$valuesArr`.

---

For debugging issues like this, echo (or vardump) the SQL text, immediately before it's executed:

```
echo "SQL=" . $sql ;
```

---

Also, the mysql_ interface is deprecated, and will not be supported in the future. New development should use either **PDO** or **mysqli**, and make use of prepared statements with bind placeholders. (But if you are stuck with mysql interface, then kudos for at least using the `mysql_real_escape_string` function to thwart SQL injection attacks.)

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Look at this line of code, and consider what happens the first time through the loop, when `$i = 1`.

```
$dob = mysql_real_escape_string( $dob[$i] );
```

Now, consider what happens the second time through the loop. Ask yourself this question: What value is currently stored in `$dob`?

Was a previous assignment done that changed the value of `$dob`? What is the result of this expression: **`$dob[2]`**, when `$dob` contains a string value such as **`'01/22/2015'`**? (Hint: we'd expect a single character to be returned.)

Comment: my bad i forgot to reset the $sql 
So i did it but the error is still the same .
and i am recieving the variables through sesion 
where reason is a dropdown and i am fetching the value via `$reason =$_SESSION['post']['reason'];`

Comment: For debugging, **echo** or **vardump** the actual SQL Text that's being submitted to the database, before it's executed. Then, figure out what's wrong with the SQL text; that will lead you to what needs to be fixed in the code.

Comment: I did some changes as Jay Blanchard suggested and the query Query worked but only the first row has the right values.
The second row is stripping the values

` INSERT INTO student (formid,firstname,lastname,dob,school,year,sex,touch,reason,other,need,improve1) values('29', '12321' , '12321' , '01/22/2015' , '321' , '3' , 'male' , 'no' , 'Intervention' , '12321' , 'no' , 'ADHDandAUTISMandDYSPRAXIAandOther')1INSERT INTO student (formid,firstname,lastname,dob,school,year,sex,touch,reason,other,need,improve1) values('29', '3' , '3' , '/' , '1' , '' , 'l' , 'no' , 't' , '3' , '' , 'fooandfoo')1`

Comment: I added a followup in my answer. The first time through the loop, you are *changing* the values that are assigned to `$firstname`, `$lastname`, `$dob`, etc. The second time through the loop, the same expressions are operating on values that are *different* from what they were the first time through the loop. (See the followup in the answer above.)

Comment: Thankyou very much for pointing me to the right direction ,Everything is working Fine now .